# CS50 Trie Week 5: check function not working

Tags: c, function, if-statement, logical-operators, trie

I have been trying to complete the trie practice problem from the CS50 course. The check function that I wrote must check whether the user input is found within the trie that has been created in the main function.

```
bool check(char* word)
{
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp = root;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++){
        int ix = tolower(name[i]) - 'a';
        if (ix < 0 || ix => SIZE_OF_ALPHABET){
            return false;
        }
        if (temp->children[ix] == NULL && temp->is_word == false){
            return false;
        }
        temp = temp->children[ix];
    }
    return true;
}
```

The program compiles and runs just fine, however, whenever I deliberately input an invalid name that should not be found, the program still outputs that the name has been found, which should not happen. Could someone please explain what my mistake is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your argument is `word` but you mostly ignore it and work on `name` instead?

Comment: OT: your first two lines immediately leak memory. Ditch the malloc, you're not using the memory you allocated.

Comment: `=>` should be `>=`.

Comment: Aside: Cast the argument to `tolower()` to an `unsigned char`.

Comment: Don't calculate the string length at every iteration. Declare another variable of `size_t` and call `strlen()` just once.

Comment: What exactly are `root` and `name`?

Comment: You need to provide the code for your trie construction. Otherwise we can't tell whether you're properly initializing the entries of `node.children` to `null`.

Comment: This condition looks wrong: `temp->children[ix] == NULL && temp->is_word == false`.  I would expect that you check `is_word` only for the node, if any, that corresponds to the full search term, not for any other node on the path to it.  Also, it doesn't matter whether that node has any children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the function should be declared like

```
bool check( const char *word );
```

because passed strings are not changed within the function.

The function produces a memory leak in this code snippet

```
node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
temp = root;
```

That is at first memory was dynamically allocated and its address was assigned to the pointer `temp` and then the pointer was reassigned. So there is no possibility in this case to free the allocated memory.

Actually neither memory should be allocated.

Using the function `strlen` is redundant.

As for your question then in this if statement

```
if (temp->children[ix] == NULL && temp->is_word == false){
```

instead of the logical AND operator there must be the logical OR operator

```
if (temp->children[ix] == NULL || temp->is_word == false){
```

The function can look the following way

```
bool check( const char *word )
{
    bool present = root != NULL && *word != '\0';

    for ( node *temp = root; present && *word; ++word )
    {
        present = isalpha( ( unsigned char )*word );
        
        if ( present )
        {
            int ix = tolower( *word ) - 'a';

            present = ix < SIZE_OF_ALPHABET && temp->children[ix] != NULL && temp->is_word;

            if ( present ) temp = temp->children[ix];
        }
    }

    return present;
}
```